# check for any missing dates in the index

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, python-datetime

Is there any way to check for missing dates in a dataframe directly.
I want to check if there are a missing dates between `2013-01-19` to `2018-01-29`

```
            GWA_BTC      GWA_ETH    GWA_LTC  GWA_XLM  GWA_XRP
   Date                 
2013-01-19  11,826.36   1,068.45    195.00    0.51    1.82
2013-01-20  13,062.68   1,158.71    207.58    0.52    1.75
   ...
2018-01-28  12,326.23   1,108.90    197.36    0.48    1.55
2018-01-29  11,397.52   1,038.21    184.92    0.47    1.43
```

I tried to check it manually but it took a lot of time.

Comment: what do you mean by missing? are they business days ?

Comment: @Yuca There are some missing dates randomly in the data. Like around 7 days are missing from `2014-07-13 to 2014-07-19`. Similarly, there are some missing dates in between the data. Is there any way we can know what dates are missing rather than checking manually?

Comment: yes but do you 365 days per year or 252?

Comment: @Yuca 365 days.

Comment: you want to know only if there are missing or what the missing dates are?

Comment: @Yuca I want to know the missing dates

Comment: @user456 Maybe edit your question, as it is written it suggest that you want a boolean.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use [DatetimeIndex.difference(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.difference.html#pandas-datetimeindex-difference)

```
pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-19', end = '2018-01-29' ).difference(df.index)
```

It returns the elements not present in the other

Comment: Just put this as an edit to my answer (will delete). But clearly this is the way to go!

Comment: @sacul, oh cool. Your answer is quite comprehensive, you should keep it

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of. `pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()).difference(df.index)`

Answer (score 4):

## Example:

As a minimal example, take this:

```
>>> df
              GWA_BTC   GWA_ETH  GWA_LTC  GWA_XLM  GWA_XRP
Date                                                      
2013-01-19  11,826.36  1,068.45   195.00     0.51     1.82
2013-01-20  13,062.68  1,158.71   207.58     0.52     1.75
2013-01-28  12,326.23  1,108.90   197.36     0.48     1.55
2013-01-29  11,397.52  1,038.21   184.92     0.47     1.43
```

And we can find the missing dates between `2013-01-19` and `2013-01-29`

## Method 1:

**See @Vaishali's answer**

<s>Use `.difference` to find the difference between your datetime index and the set of all dates within your range:</s>

```
pd.date_range('2013-01-19', '2013-01-29').difference(df.index)
```

Which returns:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-21', '2013-01-22', '2013-01-23', '2013-01-24',
               '2013-01-25', '2013-01-26', '2013-01-27'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

## Method 2:

You can re-index your dataframe using all dates within your desired daterange, and find where `reindex` has inserted `NaN`s.

And to find missing dates between `2013-01-19` and `2013-01-29`:

```
>>> df.reindex(pd.date_range('2013-01-19', '2013-01-29')).isnull().all(1)

2013-01-19    False
2013-01-20    False
2013-01-21     True
2013-01-22     True
2013-01-23     True
2013-01-24     True
2013-01-25     True
2013-01-26     True
2013-01-27     True
2013-01-28    False
2013-01-29    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

Those values with `True` are the missing dates in your original dataframe

Comment: Do i have to convert the index to datetime object? at the moment the dtype of index is object.

Comment: Yes, you should. `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Method 1 does not work? It returns all the dates between start and end rather than displaying missing dates?

Comment: No, it works, but I crossed it out because @Vaishali had already answered it using that solution

Comment: That replaces the original column(s) with True/False values. How can I keep the original columns and add the True/False as a new column?

Answer (score 2):

assuming data is daily non business dates:

```
df.index.to_series().diff().dt.days > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DatetimeIndex.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.difference.html#pandas-datetimeindex-difference) and add freq param, so you can check for missing days, hours, minutes, depending on the frequency you are using:

```
pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min").difference(df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment but you can probably traverse each value and add 24 hours to the previous value to see if the date matches?

```
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a , 'b': b})

for i in range(len(df)):
    prev = df.loc[i,'a']
    if i is 0:
        continue
    else:
         # Add 1 day to the current value and check with prev value
```