# Checking if all the dates between min and max dates present in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows.

```
pd.DataFrame({"Date":["09-01-2021","09-02-2021","09-02-2021","09-04-2021"]})
```

How do I check all the dates between max and min dates in the date column in a data frame?

Here "09-03-2021" is missing.
So expected output is ["09-03-2021"], i.e. list of all missing dates.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

How do I check all the dates between max and min dates in the date column in a data frame?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["09-01-2021","09-02-2021","09-02-2021","09-04-2021"]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df.loc[(df['Date'] > min(df['Date'])) & (df['Date'] < max(df['Date']))])
```

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-02-2021 |
| 2 | 09-02-2021 |

**EDIT**

**Question 2**

How to list of all missing dates?

Reference -
[check for any missing dates in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044348/check-for-any-missing-dates-in-the-index)

```
print(pd.date_range(start = min(df['Date']), end = max(df['Date'])).difference(df['Date']))

>>> DatetimeIndex(['2021-09-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If the dataframe in the sorted order you can try using

```
print(pd.date_range(start = df.iloc[0]['Date'], end = df.iloc[-1]['Date']).difference(df['Date']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date_range` function and check if the unique values are the same in your dataframe and the generated range -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["09-01-2021","09-02-2021","09-02-2021","09-04-2021"]})
rng = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max())
print(set(rng) == set(df['Date']))
#returns False
```